# distribute two integers according to ratio

Tags: c++

Say, I have some integer n and would like to subdivide it into two other integers according to some ratio. I have some approach where I ask myself whether it does work or not.

For example: 20 with ratio 70% should be subdivided into 14,6.

The obvious solution would be:

```
int n = 20;
double ratio = .7;
int n1 = static_cast<int>(n * ratio);
int n2 = static_cast<int>(n * (1 - ratio));
```

Since the cast always `floor`s, however, I usually underrate my result. If I use `std::round`, there are still cases that are not working. For example, if the first decimal place is a 5, then both numbers will be rounded up.

Some colleagues suggested: Ceil the first number and floor the second one. In most of my tests, this works, however:

1) Does it really always work, also taking into accounting possible rounding errors that naturally occur in multiplying numbers? What I think of: 20*.7 could be 14, while 20*.3 could be 5.999999. So, my sum might be 14 + 5 = 19. This is just my guess, however, I do not know whether these kind of results can or cannot occur (otherwise the answer would be simply that this kind of rounding proposition does not work)

2) Even if it does work... Why?

(I have in mind that I could just calculate number 1 by n * ratio and calculate number 2 by n - n * ratio, but I would still be interested in the answer to this question)

Comment: why dont you simply check after rounding if `n1+n2==n`, then you add/subtract one to make it fit if necessary

Comment: floating point to integer conversion is not `ceil` but `floor`

Comment: You presented examples that prove that any kind of rounding combination doesn't work. And you know that the subtraction method works. So what is your question?

Comment: "Since the cast always ceils"???

Comment: ... (ceil/floor) for positive numbers

Comment: the wrong ceil is changed, thanks!
@michalsrb I provided examples out of my mind, they are not result of any program. It could be that this can never happen for whatever reason... or it could be that this really is a possible case, which renders rounding up/down solutions like this unreliable. It is probably necessary to have low-level system knowledge on when/why exactly rounding errors like this can computationally occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example that confirms your suspicion and shows that the ceil+floor method doesn't always work. It is caused by the finite precision of floating point numbers on computer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    int n = 10;
    double ratio = 0.7;
    int n1 = static_cast<int>(floor(n * ratio));
    int n2 = static_cast<int>(ceil(n * (1.0 - ratio)));

    std::cout << n1 << " " << n2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
7 4
```

7 + 4 is 11, so it's wrong.

Comment: (Oh, sorry, bad answer to reply to. Please ignore).

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
int n = 20;
double ratio = .7;
int n1 = static_cast<int>(n * ratio);
int n2 = n - n1;
```

Comment: This definitely works. But the requester already wrote that he is aware of this solution...

Comment: @michalsrb Where exactly did he say that?

Comment: @ToniBig This was an edit, I mentioned it in the last paragraph. Nevertheless, my questions are preceded by 1) and 2), I did not ask for a solution to the distribution itself, although the title might be misleading

Comment: @IceFire: You did ask for a solution to the distribution. That's how you open your question: "*Say, I have some integer n and would like to subdivide it into two other integers according to some ratio. **How can I safely do this?***"

Comment: Correct and changed. My actual question is not answered but since this is not your fault, you shall at least receive an upvote

Comment: Don't cast n1, cast the round of it. Better still, compare ratio with 1/2: if greater, round (n*ratio) for n1 and get n2 by subtraction. If ratio <1/2, get n2 by round and n1 by subtraction. Rationale: rounding err/abs(rounded) is smaller as the rounded value increases.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't always work, take a ratio of 77%, you'll get 15 and 4 ([See on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d98b4c16a77a777d)).

Welcome to the domain of numerical analysis.

First, your computer can't always perfectly store a floating number. As you can see in the example, `.77` is stored as `0.77000000000000001776` (it is an approach of the number by a sum of powers of 2).

When doing floating point calculation, you will always have a loss in precision. You can get this precision with `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`.

Moreover, you'll still get more precision loss when converting from a floating number to an integer, and in your case the difference is big enough to give you an incoherent result.

The solution provided by @ToniBig and your last sentence has the advantage of "hiding" this loss and keep coherent data.